# Simulating drags inside a scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, multi-touch

:) I am working on intercepting, and resending gestures sent to a scrollview.

What I want to do:

Kill all gestureRecognizers in the scrollview. I have accomplished this.

Add new gestureRecognizers in the scrollview. I have accomplished this as well.

Make the new recognizers behave the same as the old ones. I have NOT accomplished this, and I need help doing so.

The only new recognizer I have added is a pan gesture recognizer, which requires at least two fingers. I want this to behave exactly as a one finger scroll. :)

What kind of calls must I send when responding to the callbacks generated by the new recognizer to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want two-finger scroll as in Mac OS X? And disable all other interfaces such as one-finger scroll or zoom by pinching?

Comment: Yes, but I accomplished all of those, so no worries :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've overcomplicated this by trying to implement your own custom gesture recogniser.

The UIPanGestureRecognizer class has a minimumNumberOfTouches property which you should be able to set to 2 for your UIScrollView.

To do so just grab your views gesture recognisers...

```
myScrollView.gestureRecognizers;
```

Iterate over the array to find the pan gesture...

```
if ([gestureRecogniser isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
```

Cast your gestureRecogniser pointer to the more specific type...

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecogniser = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecogniser;
```

And finally set its minimumNumberOfTouches property...

```
panGestureRecogniser.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
```

The only other thing you may have to do is enabled multitouch for your view - UIView has a multipleTouchEnabled property that should be set to true.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, You can just write

```
myScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
```