# Trying to draw inside of a uiscrollview

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, drawing, uigesturerecognizer

We would like to be able to display a large picture inside a uiscrollview which can be scrolled using two finger, and then allow the user to draw on it using one finger.

We've already made an app where you can display a background image and then draw on top of it on another uiview. We basically want to incorporate this with the uiscrollview, but we're not sure if it's possible/how to do that. If we set the uiscrollviews minimum number of touches to 2 (like the answer here [Simulating drags inside a scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125283/simulating-drags-inside-a-scrollview)), could we then use touchesBegan, touchesEnded etc for drawing, and inside of them just check to see if it was one finger and if it was draw?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else wanted to try this, it does work! We didn't really encounter any problems doing this. As long as you tell the scrollview to only respond to two finger actions it works fine.